Confused by documentation about behavior of globals() within a function
Per the Python documentation of globals():

For code within functions, this is set when the function is defined and remains the same regardless of where the function is called.

I understood this as calling globals() from within a function returns an identical dict to the one that represented the global namespace when the function was defined, even if there have been modifications to the global namespace since then.
However, my experiment below showed that my understanding is apparently incorrect. What does the documentation mean, then?
(In the example below I expected the second call of foo() to give the same result as the first. Of course, if that was the case I would question the utility of globals(), but that seems to be what the documentation means.)
def foo():
    if 'x' in globals():
        print(f"Found x: {globals()['x']}")
    else:
        global x
        x = 1
        print(f"Not found. Set x = {x}.")

foo() # Not found. Set x = 1.
foo() # Found x: 1


In fact this problem is only loosely related to the globals() builtin function but more closely related to the behaviour of mutable objects.
Long story made short, your observation is correct, and the documentation is absolutely correct and accurate.
The underlying cause, is that Python variables are only references to the actual objects. Let us look at an example:
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
b = a                 # ok, we take a "copy"
print(b)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}      # no surprise here
a['c'] = 3            # let us MUTATE the original object
print(b)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

What happens here is that both variable are references to the very same object, what can be confirmed with print(id(a), id(b))
But if we use a different object:
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}     # a is now a new and distinct object
                                 #  even if it has the same value
a['d'] = 4    
print(a, b)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4} {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

b is still a reference to the original object, so the new changes to a are not accessible through b. You can confirm that they are now distinct objects with print(id(a), id(b)).
The documentation is just a warning that if for any reason the global directory is changed to a new and different object(*), the function will still keep a reference of the object that existed when the function was defined.

(*) AFAIK, the specification of the language has no guarantee that the global directory will be the very same object during all the program lifetime

I don't think a module's globals are ever changed to a new object. Surely it's about the different globals of different modules.

A preceding sentence was left out of the OP: “Return the dictionary implementing the current module namespace.”  Each module has its own global dictionary. globals() will return the dictionary of the module where the function was defined, even if called from a different module.
